# Does the Promises polyfill include all() in Google Closure Compiler 20161024?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-closure-compiler, es6-promise

The release notes in the 20161024 release show ES3 polyfill for Promises, but when I compile with this version and test in IE11 I get an error in the console that indicates that Promise.all() is not supported:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'all'
```

(I'm using `rewrite_polyfills: 'true'` in the gulp task definition.)

If I add these console outputs:

```
console.log( 'Promise: ' + Promise );
console.log( 'Promise.all: ' + Promise.all );
```

I get this in IE11:

```
Promise: function c(b){this.b=0;this.o=void 0;this.a=[];var c=this.i();try{b(c.resolve,c.reject)}catch(p){c.reject(p)}}
Promise.all: undefined
```

and this in Chrome (which works as expected):

```
Promise: function Promise() { [native code] }
Promise.all: function all() { [native code] }
```

Is the all() method not a part of the polyfill?

Comment: `Is the all() method not a part of the polyfill?` you'd have to look at the polyfill I guess

Comment: Can you link that release, please?

Comment: Please show the line of code that is getting the error, and the definitions of the objects on that line.

Comment: @owler I edited the question. Hope that helps.

Comment: Promise.all is polyfilled, but Promise.race and Promise.all got renamed in compiled version. Not sure what to do next.

Comment: It's weird. I removed `--jscomp_warning=VERBOSE` and `--jscomp_warning=missingProperties` compiler flags and magic happens. No idea how warning level flags can affect polyfill methods renaming.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - the Polyfill includes the Promise.all definition: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/js/es6/promise.js#L507-L548

Comment: Thanks. Is there something beyond using 'rewrite_polyfills' to get this polyfill compiled into the code? Would I need to language_out to ES3, or should I be able to use the polyfill in ES5?

Comment: It's possible that the polyfilled version of Promise.all is getting renamed, which might happen if you're not using the default externs. It's also possible that it's getting dead-code eliminated because the compiler thinks (wrongly) that you're not using it. Try adding a call maybe (i.e. `Promise.all()` instead of just `Promise.all`)